# What is the proper way of notifying screen reader that Ajax call was initiated or completed

Tags: ajax, datatables, accessibility

We have a reporting web page that displays some filtering inputs and the report data (using DataTables). When user clicks the Search button or sorts the data, DataTables makes Ajax call to the server. While that's in motion we display an overlay over the table that says something like "Processing...", etc.

The question I have is, what is the proper or preferred way to notify the screen reader that the search/sort was initiated, or that the results came back and that the table was refreshed? I've searched for an answer on the web but I wasn't able to find anything definitive.

Comment: @davidkonrad no, search button is on the page, i just mentioned it to say that there are two ways to ajax, either by searching with some filtering criteria or by sorting the data. so suppose it takes 5 or 10 seconds or more to refresh the data. how would i tell screen reader (i.e. the user) that the data refresh has been completed?

Comment: More context or a code sample needed, but at the very least take a look at `aria-busy` and at ARIA live regions for the notification that the page was refreshed. Previous SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40766358/how-can-i-make-screen-readers-respond-to-showing-and-hiding-content-in-a-dynamic/40767010#40767010

Comment: @aardrian Perhaps. I would more look into the **`xhr.dt`** event, but hard to guess what OP actually need without a code example demonstrating what supposedly should happen.

Comment: @davidkonrad The XHR piece is independent of the static HTML wrappers and ARIA attributes the OP needs. Both will need to be addressed, either independently or through a solution that has it all built in. But yeah, need to see the code.

Comment: Hey @aardrian In dataTables `xhr.dt` is fired each and every time an AJAX request is *completed*. See **https://datatables.net/reference/event/xhr** and when using `serverSide` (as I *assume* OP does) `xhr.dt` will be fired after each and every filtering and sorting, no matter how the filtering or sorting is initiated. But then again, does not even know for sure we are talking about jQuery dataTables :)

Comment: @aardrian and davidkonrad - thank you for your answers. i think xhr.dt event combined with aria-live and aria-busy should work. i'll test with NVDA to see if that's the case. Thank you, much appreciated!